# Drawing arrows using d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In this fiddle I'm attempting to draw an arrow :

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1200)
            .attr("height", 1200)
            .attr("text-align" , "center");

    var arrowStartPosition = 5
    var arrowSpacing = 60
    var verticalStrokeColor = "black"
    var arrowYStartPosition = 5
    var arrowYEndStartPosition = 150
    var margin = 150;

    var labelLine = svgContainer.append("line")
            .attr("x1", arrowStartPosition + margin)
            .attr("y1", arrowYStartPosition)
            .attr("x2", arrowStartPosition + margin)
            .attr("y2", arrowYEndStartPosition)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", verticalStrokeColor);

    var right = svgContainer.append("line")
            .attr("x1", arrowStartPosition + margin)
            .attr("y1", arrowYStartPosition)
            .attr("x2", 20 + margin)
            .attr("y2", 20)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");

    var left = svgContainer.append("line")
            .attr("x1", right.attr("x1")-15)
            .attr("y1", right.attr("y1")+15)
            .attr("x2", 5 + margin)
            .attr("y2", 5)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");
```

To try and keep the code generic I'm attempting to keep draw the left part of arrow depending on position of right :

```
.attr("y1", right.attr("y1")+15)
```

But as can be seen in fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3447/

the arrow is not being drawn correctly.

I think this is because the `right.attr("y1")` value is not initialized at time of drawing ?

Any pointers on a more elegant method of achieving same result appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26789005/2) summary (wanted to write 'http:// to https://').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to define left's position based on right's position, the only value that needs to be changed is `x2`.

```
var left = svgContainer.append("line")
        .attr("x1", right.attr("x1"))
        .attr("y1", right.attr("y1"))
        .attr("x2", right.attr("x2")-30)
        .attr("y2", right.attr("y2"))
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("stroke", "black");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3448/)

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript required! Use SVG `<marker/>`:

```html
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <marker id="arrow-head" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="5" refy="5" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,10 L10,5 L0,0" style="fill: #000000;" />
      </marker>
    </defs>

    <path d="M0,0 L10,20 L20,50 L30,30 L40,40 L50,50" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none; marker-end: url(#arrow-head);"/>
  </svg>
```

[Here's a demo in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/burita/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: thanks but I will be drawing multiple lines and arrows. Even if your code is idiomatic it's too much abstraction for me to grasp how to link these lines together. I'm starting out with d3 so maybe in time could use something like what you provided.